# yesware tracking link showing that link is opened from my IP address also the link is opened in different IP at the same time

Tags: email, security, ip, ip-address, tracking

I am testing yesware track emails, I am sending a test email to my email address while clicking the link in the email it's showing that link is opened from my IP address also the link is opened in different IP at the same time, just worried is my email is hacked, confused any suggestions

That IP address is

62.243.69.215,
159.203.42.143,
159.203.81.93

Answer (score 1):

### Sorry to be the bearer of bad news

As you can see in the comments section of these IP lookup results, a few other people have marked down that the last two IP addresses **are** associated with hacking / spam. Take a look at the "User Comments" on the following

- It is obvious that IP Address 1 belongs to you
- [IP Address 2 Result](https://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/159.203.81.93)
- [IP Address 3 Result](https://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/159.203.42.143)

### What you can do about it

**First**, my advice would be to run your computer in safe mode and do some virus checks. You can use any software you like for this, but I would recommend using a well-known and reputable tool. Run a complete & detailed scan so that you ensure the safety and integrity of your information

**Next**, change your password! Seriously - go and get yourself a password manager if you want the added layer of having a strong password that can't easily be guessed. You want it to be tough to crack.

**Lastly**, absolutely do **not** post your password online anywhere. Do not give it to friends, do not write it down on a sticky note, and do not save it into a text file on your desktop. Let your password manager do its job and manage your password! **Do not give your password out to anyone - not even someone who claims to work for the email company!**

---

**EDIT**: If you use the same email address and password for *any* other websites, change those passwords too. If you use the same credentials for your Amazon account, eBay account, PayPal etc. then you **MUST** change them separately. The attacker may try your current combination and gain access to other accounts if you don't do this.

Comment: thanks it's only happening when I click the link from my iPhone(only in my safari browser), it not happening on the computer

Answer (score 1):

We've found that iPhones and Androids typically end up creating two notifications for an open event. When a mobile device opens the email, two data requests are made - one from the IP of the phone and one from the IP of a data center. Since there are two unique requests with different IPs and "locations", we send you two notifications. If you think something else might be at play, would you mind sending the details to through our support center at help.yesware.com? We'd be happy to check it out!

Thank you!

Carolyn
- Manager, Customer Experience at Yesware